# C# - WCF: There was no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, console-application

I've looked and a few similar questions but none seem to help. I'm trying to get to grips with WCF, the reason being I want to create a Windows Service that I can connect to with a Windows Form application. I've followed a few tutorials and have created the following Windows service that is installed and running on my Windows 7 device:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;

[ServiceContract]
public interface HelloWorld
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string value);
}

public class Hello : HelloWorld
{
    public string SayHello(string value)
    {
        string retVal = "";
        if (value == "Hello")
        {
            retVal = "Hello World!";
        }
        else
        {
            retVal = "Say hello to me...";
        }
        return (retVal);
    }
}

class PluginService : ServiceBase
{
    public PluginService()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "Test Plugin Service";
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanShutdown = true;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new PluginService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Hello),
          new Uri[]{
          new Uri("http://localhost:8998"),
          new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
        }))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(HelloWorld), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Hello");
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(HelloWorld), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeHello");
            host.Open();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {  

    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {

    }

}
```

I have also created a very basic console application that should connect to the service. The idea is you say "Hello" through this console utility, and the service returns "Hello World":

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;


namespace PluginApplication
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface HelloWorld
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string value);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChannelFactory<HelloWorld> httpFactory =
              new ChannelFactory<HelloWorld>(
                new BasicHttpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(
                  "http://localhost:8998/Hello"));

            ChannelFactory<HelloWorld> pipeFactory =
              new ChannelFactory<HelloWorld>(
                new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(
                  "net.pipe://localhost/PipeHello"));

            HelloWorld httpProxy = httpFactory.CreateChannel();
            HelloWorld pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Say something...");
                    string str = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("http: " +
                      httpProxy.SayHello(str));
                    Console.WriteLine("pipe: " +
                      pipeProxy.SayHello(str));
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the console and input "Hello", I get the following error after a few seconds:

> *System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listeniong at http://localhost:8998/Hello that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8998
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)*

Firewall is fully disabled on my device, so I'm really not sure why it says the target machine actively refused the connection. Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `using` construct in the `OnStart()` method. This means that once that method completes, the `ServiceHost` object you created will no longer be available, and therefore the endpoint you defined will not be available either. Instead, store the `ServiceHost` variables somewhere statically in your windows service.

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to tweak my code now and it does work. :)